# dealing with blank rows in python function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
a      b      c
foo    bar    baz
bar    foo    baz
foobar barfoo baz
       foobar foo
```

I've written a simple function:

```
def somefunction (row):
    if row['a'] == 'foo' and row['b'] == 'bar':
        return 'yes'
    if '' in row['a']:
        return 'no'
    return 'no'
```

I'm trying to deal with blank rows in the dataframe, such that, if the row in column `[a]` is `blank` then the function should return `no`
But I want to explicitly define in the function to check for blank rows

But I get the following error:

`"argument of type 'float' is not iterable"`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: [You're suffering from the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual goal?

Comment: My goal is find a way to deal with blank rows by correctly assigning a value to it.
I don't want to remove the blank rows, because they are an integral part of the dataframe.

Comment: Did you try using `df = df.fillna(some_value)`?